# Как из Asynctask получить доступ к MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, static, weather

Мне нужна помощь, создал приложение погода, вот код

Класс Weather

```
public class Weather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private String result = "";
private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        int data = reader.read();

        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            result = result.concat(String.valueOf(current));
            data = reader.read();
        }
        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject info = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("main"));
        JSONObject wind = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("wind"));

        double temperature = Double.parseDouble(info.getString("temp"));
        int temp_Celsius = (int) (temperature - 273.15);
        String pressure = info.getString("pressure");
        String humidity = info.getString("humidity");
        String windSpeed = wind.getString("speed");
        String place = jsonObject.getString("name");

        String weather = jsonObject.getString("weather");
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(weather);
        String description = "";
        int id = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject arrayObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            description = arrayObject.getString("description");
            id = arrayObject.getInt("id");
        }

        setWeatherIcon(id, jsonObject.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunrise") * 1000,
                jsonObject.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunset") * 1000);

        MainActivity.city.setText(place.toUpperCase());
        MainActivity.temperature.setText(String.valueOf(temp_Celsius + "°C"));
        MainActivity.details.setText("Weather: " + description + "\n" + "Pressure: " + pressure + "hpa" + "\n" + "Humidity: " + humidity + "\n" + "Wind speed: " + windSpeed + "m/s");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setWeatherIcon(int actualId, long sunrise, long sunset) {
    int id = actualId / 100;
    long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (actualId == 800) {
        if (currentTime >= sunrise && currentTime < sunset) {
            MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sun);
        } else MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.night);
    } else {
        if (currentTime >= sunrise && currentTime < sunset) {
            switch (id) {
                case 7:
                    MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.partly_cloudy);
                    break;
            }
        } else if (currentTime <= sunrise && currentTime > sunset) {
            switch (id) {
                case 7:
                    MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
                    break;
            }
        } else switch (id) {
            case 2:
                MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunder);
                break;
            case 3:
                MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.storm);
                break;
            case 5:
                MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rain);
                break;
            case 6:
                MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.snow);
                break;
            case 8:
                MainActivity.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloud);
                break;
        }
    }
}}
```

Класс Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView city;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView temperature;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static TextView details;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public static ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    city = findViewById(R.id.city);
    temperature = findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    details = findViewById(R.id.details);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);

    try {
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        weather.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Yerevan&appid=53328692679f840d7be7c1d520a324d1").get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.change_city) {
        showInputDialog();
    }
    return false;
}

private void showInputDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Change city");
    final EditText inputCity = new EditText(this);
    inputCity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(inputCity);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            try {
                Weather weather = new Weather();
                weather.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + inputCity.getText().toString() +
                        "&appid=53328692679f840d7be7c1d520a324d1").get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Есть 2 класса, вы это уже видите) но там есть несколько View элементов в MainActivity (TextView, ImageView), и их я использую в классе Weather, но их надо делать статик в MainActivity, а так код нечистый... как можно решить эту проблему??

Comment: что-то вроде слушателя можно прилепить https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Вот так `public static TextView city` делать нельзя.

Comment: @post_zeew автор как раз и спрашивает, как от этого избавиться. Хочет вернуться на правильный путь.

Comment: @eugeneek, Ну я так, мимо пробегал, а это в глаза бросилось :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов сделать класс `Weather` внутренним нестатическим классом `MainActivity` и тогда в нём будет неявная ссылка на класс активити `MainActivity.this`, через которую вы сможете получить доступ к её полям.

Другой вариант, явно передать объект `MainActivity` в класс `Weather` через конструктор `Weather weather = new Weather(this);`, сохранить в локальную переменную и обращаться к её полям.

```
public class Weather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ...
    private MainActivity activity;

    public Weather(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ...
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.city.setText(place.toUpperCase());
            activity.temperature.setText(String.valueOf(temp_Celsius + "°C"));
            activity.details.setText("Weather: " + description + "\n" + "Pressure: " + pressure + "hpa" + "\n" + "Humidity: " + humidity + "\n" + "Wind speed: " + windSpeed + "m/s");
        }
        ...
    }

    public void release() {
        activity = null;
    }
}
```

В `MainActivity`:

```
private Weather weather;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    weather = new Weather(this);
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    weather.release();
}
```

В первом варианте вы можете получить утечку активити пока не будет завершено выполнение `AsyncTask`. Во втором вы можете этого избежать, вручную зануляя ссылку на активити, например, в методе `onDestroy()`. Но при этом при обращении к её полям нужно будет добавить проверку на `null`.

Comment: Тоже так думаю, первый способ подойдет

Comment: Действительно, первый способ проще, но может привести к утечке памяти. Я бы рекомендовал второй. Вы же хотите, чтобы было "чисто".

Comment: Да, но как передать объект MainActivity в класс Weather через конструктор Weather weather = new Weather(this);

Comment: Ладно это передал, но на Weather классе в каком месте его реализовать?

Comment: Обновил ответ с примером кода.

Comment: Понял, но есть еще проблема)) смотри в классе Weather этот private MainActivity activity; тоже ругается, ну утечка памяти говорит))

Comment: Для этого в `onDestroy()` мы его обнуляем. Утечки не будет. Просто lint это не может отследить, поэтому и предупреждает.

Comment: колбеки проще использовать

Comment: @PeterDroid Вам никто не мешает дать ответ со своим вариантом.